# Why main() is not required for servlet? Although servlet is a java class which deploy on Server side

Tags: java, servlets, methods, server, program-entry-point

I want to get detailed understand in layman words, Why servlet has no main method.Who will take role of main method on servlet as we know servlet is also a java program that runs on server side and by default it called doGet() method.How can web application start without main method as we are just call it from a link.